# Surface Area Multivariable Calculus

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

Find the surface area of the portion of the sphere $x^2$ + $y^2$ + $z^2$ = 25 that lies inside the cylinder $x^2$ + $y^2$ = 9.

My attempt at a solution: $z^2$ = 25 - $x^2$ - $y^2$, so z = $\sqrt{25 - x^2 - y^2}$. Then, partials of z: $\frac{-x}{\sqrt{25 - x^2 - y^2}}$ and $\frac{-y}{\sqrt{25 - x^2 - y^2}}$.

So, SA = $\int$$\int$ $\sqrt{1 + \frac{x^2}{25 - x^2 - y^2} + \frac{y^2}{25 - x^2 - y^2}}$dydx. Converting to polar:

$\int$$\int$ $\sqrt{1 + \frac{r^2cos^2\theta}{{25 - r^2}} + \frac{r^2sin^2\theta}{{25 - r^2}}}rdrd\theta$, and simplifying and adding limits of integration gives $$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^3 \sqrt{1 + \frac{r^2}{25-r^2}} rdrd\theta$$.

I'm stuck as to where to go from here. I guess I could've made a mistake earlier in the problem but I'm confident with what I have so far.

Comment: Continue from your work we have $$\sqrt{\frac{25}{25-r^2}}$$, I think you can move on!

Comment: @Crazy how exactly did you get there?

Comment: $$ \sqrt{\frac{25-r^2}{25-r^2}+\frac{r^2}{25-r^2}}$$ That is the trick! Now it is just basic integration which you are able to see!

Comment: @Crazy Thanks... I ended up getting $10\pi$ when the answer is double that. Not sure what went wrong.

Comment: Your forgot the lower half of the sphere inside the cone! What you got is just the upper part of the sphere! We know that they are same in surface area! So no need to do work. Just double the answer you got for the upper part and we will got the total surface area as desired!

Comment: @Crazy So my limits of integration should've gone from 0 to $4\pi$? If not, where did my work go wrong? I guess maybe the issue was I only had the positive square root of z, giving me the top half of the sphere inside the cylinder...

Comment: No need to integrate until $4 \pi$ $x^2+y^2+z^2=25$. Know that square root will product plus minus sign. You just take the positive one which is the upper part of the sphere!

Comment: Glad to help!!! Try to answer your own question!

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider the spherical coordinates: 
$$x = r \sin(\theta) \cos(\varphi)\\
y = r \sin(\theta) \sin(\varphi)\\
z = r \cos(\theta)\\
$$
$$
r \in [0, + \infty) \\
\theta \in [0, \pi] \\
\varphi \in [0, 2 \pi)
$$
Here $(r, \theta, \varphi)$ stand for the radius, inclination, azimuth correspondingly.

Note that the region you are looking for is the union of two hemispheres of the same surface area.

The spherical volume form is $$dV = r^{2} \sin\theta \, dr \, d \theta \, d \varphi$$

Finally, the problem reduces to the following computation:
$$V = 2 \int_{R} {d V} = 2 \int_{0}^{\arccos(\frac{3}{5})} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} {25 \sin \theta \, d \theta \, d \varphi} = 50 \cdot 2 \pi \cdot (-(\frac{3}{5}-1)) = 40 \pi$$
(if i'm not mistaken, of course)

Comment: Answer should be $20\pi$, not exactly sure what went wrong.